# Given an array of integers, find out if there are 7 integers that satisfy 2 inequalities, if so, print out their maximum sum

Tags: greedy

Thank you in advance for helping out. I have been trying to debug my greedy solution for hours to no avail. This is actually a codeforces problem and I've been trying to figure out why my solution keeps failing the hidden tests on the site. Below is a simplified version of the problem but here is the original link containing the hidden test cases https://codeforces.com/gym/102979/problem/J:

Given an array of N integers x_1, x_2, ...., x_n, where 7 <= N <= 5 * 10^5, and 1 <= x_i <= 2 * 10^8, where x_i is not strictly distinct, find out if there are 7 integers i_1, i_2, ..., i_7 from the given N integers such that the following 2 inequalities are held:

1. i_1 >= i_2 >= i_3 >= i_4 >= i_5 >= i_6 >= i_7
2. i_1 < i_2 + i_3 < i_4 + i_5 + i_6 + i_7

If there are such 7 integers, print out their maximum sum, otherwise, print out -1.

Examples:

Input:
N = 7,
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Output:
-1

Input:
N = 10
nums = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5]

Output: 35

Here is my solution using a greedy method:

```
def fair_distribution(N, nums):

    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    x1 = 0
    while x1 < N - 6:
        x2 = x1 + 1
        x3 = x1 + 2
        sum_x2_x3 = nums[x2] + nums[x3]
        while x2 < N - 5:
            # if x1 >= x2 + x3, move to the next smaller x1, since all smaller combos of x2 & x3 would also fail the inequality
            if nums[x1] >= sum_x2_x3:
                break
            sum_x4_x7 = nums[x3+1] + nums[x3+2] + nums[x3+3] + nums[x3+4]
            while x3 < N - 4:
                if sum_x2_x3 < sum_x4_x7:
                    return nums[x1] + sum_x2_x3 + sum_x4_x7
                # if x2 + x3 >= x4, move to the next smaller x2 + x3, since all smaller combos of x4, x5, x6, x7 would also fail the inequality                
                x3 += 1
                # check if first condition still holds, if not, skip to next x1
                if sum_x2_x3 >= nums[x1]:
                    break
            x2 += 1
        x1 += 1
    
    return -1

N = int(input())
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(fair_distribution(N, nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like how you formulated the problem very concisely in your own words.

There are several things that need to be fixed in your algorithm/code. I guess this is written in Python?
Three examples:

- You keep changing the indices `x2` and `x3`, but you do not update the variables `sum_x2_x3` and `sum_x4_x7` accordingly.
- The variable `x3` should probably be initialised as `x3 = x2 + 1` in the while loop (`while x2 < N - 5:`).
- The break condition `if sum_x2_x3 >= nums[x1]:` should be `=<` instead of `>=`.

Here is an example input, where your code gives the wrong output:

```
8
6 5 3 2 2 2 2 2
```

This has the solution `[6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` and should return `21`.

Hope that helps!